# Cannot create csv file from python in visual studio code

Tags: python, csv

I am a beginner learning programming through CS50, currently on week 7 SQL.

I am trying to apply some basic principles on my own machine instead of CS50 IDE on AWS to make sure I can use other environments.

I use visual studio code on windows, and I am currently struggling on some simple lines of code, which are working on the IDE environment but not on my machine. I am simply trying to create a csv file from python, but when I run my code it executes but no csv file is created. Here is my code:

```py
import csv

with open('mycsv.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
    writer.writerow(['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Perhaps you're just looking for the file in the wrong place. Since you're not using a full path and are just specifying a file name, then the file is written in the current working directory. See `os.get_cwd()` or something similar. I'm on my phone and cannot be bothered to check.

Comment: for debugging - Instead of  `mycsv.csv` specify a full path `d:\path\to\folder\file.csv`

Comment: if you don't have  a workspace opened in VSC the current working directory might be unknown, you can specify the `cwd` in the `launch.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try w+ instead of w? Like this:

```py
import csv

with open('mycsv.csv', 'w+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
    writer.writerow(['one', 'two', 'three'])`
```

w+ forces python to create a new file if that file doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in a virtual environment, the script is creating the file in a different folder, look for the folders above.